# Extract information from recognized text business card scanner in android app

Tags: android, nlp, ocr, named-entity-recognition, google-mlkit

I have developed android app with Business Card OCR scanning feature. Using MlKit text recognization, got the text from the image taken. I was extract information of website, email, phone number. But now I am facing difficulties to detect human name, address and Company Name. Because business card structure/format is not specific, even in some case I can identify the address, but it's difficult to identify the human name and company name.

For example

[image]

In above business card regex detect RKB Solution as person name, but R. Krishnamoorthy was the person name

another case was, In card scaned text it detect "James Smith" and Some "Pixel Fusion" is company name, so issue is as per regex patter James Smith and Pixel Fusion both are person name, or both are company name.
So please guide me the right direction.

Comment: I believe the category of research is called "Named Entity Recognition problem".  Reminder that `asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Comment: @MorrisonChang, Thank you for your response, If I know particular name or word or category as you mention in your response, then directly I ask for that particular category or search on the internet, but I don't know about that, and if the beginner or the developer who are new in some specific tech then its obviously that he/she don't know about everything, So in that case I don't think, this this is off topic.
And thanks for informing me the category name "Named Entity Recognition problem".
Please guide me how I find my question's solution.

Comment: The easiest solution is to have the user label the found strings in your app as errors/typos/mistakes will happen. If you want to specify the found strings automatically / automagically then look at the category for understanding the complexity of the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Is there any blog or tutorial for NER implementation in android.
Because I check too many sites blogs, git project but not getting proper solution for android implementation.
So if any one know please comment.